# C# Different but similar Namespaces cause errors

Tags: c#, namespaces

I currently have to deal with two different namespaces.

The first namespace is from a class library and looks like this: `Autodesk.DataManagement.Client.[...]`

The second one is a wrapper library I am coding and has the namespace: `My.Autodesk.Wrapper[...]`

My problem is that this is throwing tons of errors because the IDE can't make a difference between my namespace and the namespace of the library (I use both libraries in the same class)

This is the error I get `Error  CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Connectivity' does not exist in the namespace 'My.Autodesk' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

EDIT for additional information:

Currently my library only contains a `Connection` Class and a `IConnection` interface.

Without referencing my wrapper library the code in the main project works fine:
[image: Code works fine]

But after referencing my library everything in the main project breaks:
[image]

It looks like it is mistaking my library with the Autodesk library just because I have the term `Autodesk` in my namespace.

What would be the solution? Do I really have to rename my library?

Comment: eeeehm, the error clearly shows there's no naming-conflict, but the type simply does not exist in your wrapper-namespace. Having said this we have no idea what `Connectivity` is and where it is defined.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain It does not exist because I don't need it. I just wrap certain classes I need to test. "Connectivity" is nor required in my library.

Comment: when it's not need, where exactly does the error occur? Please provide some sample code, it's really hard to guess what you're talking about.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I have added additional information now

Comment: [Namespace alias operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/namespace-alias-qualifier). Note especially `global`. But you'd probably save (future you, other coders) headaches by avoiding using a name you know is going to frequently be needing such a workaround for.

Answer (score 1):

try using this format
`using YourClass = My.Autodesk.Wrapper.[..].YourClass`

Comment: that would help if there *was* a naming-conflict. However that error does not occur because of a conflict, but because the type simply does not exist.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain It is a naming conflict. This error is caused directly after I reference my DLL. Otherwise it would work fine (and use the library classes of the Autodesk) library

Comment: can you give more information on what you are trying to do

Comment: @Nour I am creating wrapper classes for the Autodesk library in order to make them mockable and my code testable. The C# moq Nuget package only supports abstract classes and interfaces, the Autodesk library unfortunately does not provide that.

My Idea is to create wrapper classes for all classes of the Autodesk Library and use the wrapper classes instead of the Autodesk classes.

Comment: my answer should work then. or maybe rename your class to ConnectivityWrapper